# 45mb File Exceeds the Maximum Execution Time

Tags: uploads

I'm trying to upload a file which is 45mb full of images via plugin **Media From FTP** but it always got an error saying:

> Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Is it normal that a 45 mb file to exceed the max execution time?

How should I upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. Unless you have a connection that is being interrupted, or is very slow. Here is what you can do:

**Option 1**

Increase the PHP max execution time. Ask your host provider to increase it, or if you have access to it, update this line in your `php.ini` file:

`max_execution_time = 999`

**Option 2**

Use a more stable connection with a higher transfer rate. Your host maybe also suffering from bandwidth limitation because of a low quality provider, or a peak in traffic.

**Option 3**

Use a file transfer program such as [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to upload your file straight using FTP.

**Option 4**

Divide your ZIP files into separate files and then upload the individually. This will be your last option if you can't do any of the above.